# Joomla automatically adds domain in URL

Tags: php, joomla

I moved a Joomla website from one server to another.

But afterwards something strange happened.
When I enter the URL Joomla automatically adds the domain in the URL twice.

Example:

```
http://example.com/example.com/index.php/nl/
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem.

The url must be:

```
http://example.com/index.php/nl/
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check .htaccess file on the root. there must be something which is being added to the route.

Comment: .htaccess isn't activated yet. It is still called htaccess.txt